# How to apply a function to a mixed type Pandas DataFrame in place?

Tags: python, pandas

This is how I apply a function to Pandas dataframe, it works in place and modifies the original data frame.

```
df  = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0],
                    [0,0,0],
                    [0,0,0]],
                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

def add_one(x) :
    x['b'] = x['b'] + 1
    return x

df.apply(add_one, axis=1)
```

But if I try the same on this data frame (it has ints and floats instead of just ints), then it fails to apply inplace and always returns a dataframe. But I have a huge dataframe, so I want to do it inplace.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1.0,0],
                   [0,1.0,0],
                   [0,1.0,0]],
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Can you help me out?  (and why this behavior in the first place!)

thank you.

Comment: does it matter if you try `x['b']+=1`?

Comment: What version pandas are you using, it works in `0.13.1`

Comment: Hmm, you are correct in that the behaviour is different, to me the second code example behaviour is correct as there is nothing in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) to suggest that it should modify inplace

Comment: @EdChum I am at 0.12.0, Will try the new version.

Comment: See my latest comment, `0.13.1` also exhibits the same behaviour, my interpretation of the documentation is that it shouldn't modify in place as you expect so you should assign, you could do `df['b'] = df['b'].apply(add_one)` I'm guessing this isn't what you are really doing and that your function is a bit more complicated than this

Comment: So no way to apply a function in-place to a DataFrame in pandas?

Comment: But of course it'll return a frame, apply returns a frame, this seems to work inplace for me in 0.13.1 (even with floats). Generally you'll want to vectorize rather than use apply, obviously here, as mentioned above, you'd use `x['b']+=1`. Also, I think using iterrows is preferable to using apply like this.

Comment: almost all pandas operations return a new frame; inplace is rarely more memory efficient unless you have a single dtyped frame (and even then usually a copy is made).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every elements in a column have the same dtype, so when you get a column `Series` from a `DataFrame`,
they share memory.

But if you get a row `Series` from a `DataFrame`, it may not contain the same dtype values, in this
case you will get a copy of the data that converted to general dtype.

I the following code, `df.apply(f, axis=1)` pass every row to the function, that contains the copy 
of the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1.0,0],
                   [0,1.0,0],
                   [0,1.0,0]],
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

def f(x):
    x.values[0] += 1
    return x

df.apply(f, axis=0) #pass every column to f, this will change the original dataframe
print df

df.apply(f, axis=1) #pass every row to f, this will not change the original dataframe
print df
```

Comment: I realise this does answer the question (well), but using apply with side-effects seems hacky/wrong/I really dislike it!